# Visual Studio 2015 Community: PNG Editor Error - "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, png, image-editing

My Visual Studio has been encountering an error for quite a while now.  Every time I try to edit a PNG image file in Visual Studio, when I click on most buttons, an error message pops up.

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101
```

A list of the buttons (and keys) affected are:

1. The delete key
2. The advanced menu and everything underneath it
3. A, R, G, and B channel buttons
4. Grid button
5. Fit image in window button
6. Fit image width in window button
7. Zoom button
8. Pan button

Any help would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is known behavior **after VS Update1** and irritates me every time I try to edit *.png*. This is really annoying!. Microsoft Team is working on it.
[Link to original answer on msdn.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29de2c99-8712-4e0d-9904-849286dffe97/problems-using-graphics-tools-editors-and-designers-after-vs2015-update-1-error-0x80020101?forum=vsga)

I've copied it (for the case if it would be removed later)

> The Visual Studio Graphics Tools team has identified a bug that causes several of the graphical editors to either not open or fail to operate as designed after installing Update 1. Affected files include scenes (.fbx), shaders (.dgsl), and some image types (.png). The typical erroneous behavior seen is either XML text being shown rather than a graphical editor or receiving a dialog box indicating that an 0x80020101 error occurred. We have a fix in hand and are working to make it generally available before the end of January 2016.
>
> To work around the problem until we release the fix, please consider one of the following workarounds.
>
> 1. Head on over to [this OneDrive folder](http://1drv.ms/1UOfimF). This folder contains a zip file called VsGraphicsScripts.zip. The zip itself contains a folder called "Scripts". Extract the contents of the zip file somewhere convenient for you. After doing so replace the Scripts folder installed by Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\VsGraphics\Assets\Scripts with the new Scripts folder you just extracted.
> 2. Make use of the [Community Edition of Visual Studio 2013](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=532495&clcid=0x409) to do the editing you need to do on the affected files
> 3. Uninstall Update 1
>
> We sincerely apologize for the trouble,
>
> Jim Griesmer
>
> Visual Studio Graphics Tools